# Eclipse Junit cannot run my test class: it displays "invalid project specified" message

Tags: eclipse, maven, junit, test-class

I am trying to run my test classes using Junit test class in Eclipse maven project.It works fine for some projects and after copying and changing the name of the project Junit fails to start while other part of my project is working well. I tried :

1. restarting, renaming, cleaning etc. It was working for some time.
2. I have also tried to run: Task Context Test configuration.

   It fail to start  totally... it show me "Problem Launching Junit Test" followed by"invalid project specified"  message box.
   Any one who knows how to get ride of this problem?......

Comment: Are you sure you changed all the names to match the new project after copying - pasting your tests?

Comment: Helo randombee, yes I have changed the name of my project after copying it. Here is what happen:1. Changing several times over the project's name finally make it work for me. But I want to know about the cause of the problem as this is happening to me several times. Thank you for your share!

Comment: I would say that probably copying exactly the same project is messing with the internal settings. Next time try creating a project from scratch and copying only the classes you need / importing them. Maybe that fixes your problem :)

Comment: Yeh, that is what I guess as the problem. Thank you for your help.